# Convert input into WEI?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, wei

I'm currently testing a smart contract that allows users to mint my token.
I've converted each token price in Wei and wonder if the input to mint a token should be in Wei to in hardhat.
For example, if I want to test the mint function for a user who mints one single token, should I use 1 as an input or 1e18?
Thanks!

Comment: In the frontend/Dapp the user should give 1 and in the smart contract the input should be 1e18

Answer (score 0):

The contract will need 1e18 as input, you could allow the user to input as 1 and convert that to 1e18 using something like ethersjs BigNumber and then do the transaction.